# Java FileNotFoundExeception not working

Tags: java, input, exception, output

In my current project I am having an issue with not receiving a file not found exception.  My driver file passes the path to be opened to the constructor that is building a library of books.  I am using JFileChooser to get the path.  In trying to force an error (entering the name of a file that does not exist), it builds the library with no information in it, and does not throw an error.

**Driver Code:**

```
//open an existing library
                        JFileChooser dlg = new JFileChooser ("LibraryData");
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter ("Text Files", "txt");
                        dlg.setFileFilter(filter);
                        dlg.setDialogTitle("Select Existing File");
                        dlg.setApproveButtonToolTipText("Select the file you want to open and click me.");
                        int button = dlg.showOpenDialog(null);
                        if (button == dlg.APPROVE_OPTION)
                        {
                            currentPath = dlg.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                            library = new PersonalLibrary(currentPath);
                            System.out.println("===========================================================");
                            System.out.println("File opened successfully from: \n" + currentPath);
                            System.out.println("===========================================================");
                        }
                        Util.enterToContinue();
                        Util.clearScreen();
                        break;
```

**Library Code:**

```
public PersonalLibrary(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            File myFile = new File(path);
            if (myFile.exists())
            {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
                while(input.hasNext())
                {
                     //code that populates the library
                }
                input.close();
                saveNeeded = false;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `File#exists()` checks if a file is existing or not. If it does, it returns true and goes into your if block.

Since the file is not there, it just simply skips the if block and moves on. Since no attempt was made to access a non-existing file object, the exception is not thrown.

If you would like to throw an exception, you have to do so yourself like this,

```
 if(file.exists()) {
   //do file operation
 } else {
   throw new FileNotFoundException("Oops! No file...");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your checking if the file exists the catch block will never be executed.

```
if(myFile.exists())
```

If it doesn't exist nothing else will be executed including catch block.  FileNotFoundException could not occur in this block of code. If you want to catch FileNotFoundException get rid of the if block.  Or just add an else block and do you processing there whatever processing you want to do when a file doesn't exist.